# What can we get when the limit for multiplying an infinite function by a function is a constant value

Tags: limits

I am not good at solving the limit questions.Here is a problem I encoutered:

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac 1xln(1+x+\frac {f(x)}x)=3$

$\lim_{x\to 0}ln(1+x+\frac {f(x)}x)=0$

$\lim_{x\to 0}(x+\frac {f(x)}x)=0$

My question is how the latter two formulas are derived when the first formula is given?

This is my first to ask question here.I am sorry that some statements may not be correct.How can I solve this problem?Thanks for your help!

Comment: `how the three formulas are derived step by step?` Derived from what? The formulas are certainly not true for arbitrary $f(x)$ so you must know something more about it, which you should state in the question.

Comment: @dxiv I am sorry I didn't make it clear. What I means is how the latter two formulas are derived when the first formula is given? I have edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: 0/0 forms may give a finite value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for the $1^{st}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\ln\left(1+x+\frac {f(x)}x\right) & = \lim_{x\to 0} x\,\frac{1}{x}\,\ln\left(1+x+\frac {f(x)}x\right) \\ & = \left(\lim_{x\to 0} x\right)\,\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}\,\ln\left(1+x+\frac {f(x)}x\right)\right) \\ & = 0 \cdot 3 \\ & = 0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks so much! It really helps me!